# Vimでオプションの存在を確認しつつ設定する関数やコマンド

Tags: vim

複数環境で同じ`.vimrc`を使っているのですが、Vimのバージョンが違ったりしてオプションが存在しないと`set`するときにエラーが起きます。

オプションごとにいちいち`if exists('+option')`するのが面倒なので`call setoption('option')`などとすればオプションの存在を確認しつつ設定してくれる関数（またはコマンド）が欲しいのですが、そのようなことは可能でしょうか？　または他に何か良い方法はありますか？

Answer (score 8, accepted):

存在しないオプションを無視する程度なら、`:silent!`でエラーメッセージを表示させないのもアリかと思います。

例:

```
:silent! set conceallevel=2
```

http://vim-jp.org/vimdoc-ja/various.html#:silent!

Comment: あっ、それで良いです！　`:silent!`でエラーも無視できたのですね。ありがとうございます！

Answer (score 4):

```
function! SetOption(opname, val) abort
    if exists('+' . a:opname)
        execute printf('set %s=%s', a:opname, a:val)
    endif
endfunction

call SetOption('conceallevel', 2)
```

こういうのはどうでしょうか？

Comment: なるほど、`execute`を利用するのですね。この関数だとvalueを取らない切替オプションに対応できなさそうですが、参考になります。

Comment: 上のコメントの「silent!」の方法がシンプルで良いかと思います。